# How do you save the MRU List from Delphi's IDE?

Tags: delphi, ide, mru

I just upgraded from Delphi 10.3.1 to Delphi 10.3.2. I exported the migration settings so I could import them immediately after the upgrade was completed.

Unfortunately the "migration settings" does not include the MRU (Most Recently Used) list of Delphi projects and files I had been working with within the 10.3.1 IDE.

It's probably too late now because I did a complete uninstall of Delphi 10.3.1 before doing the install of Delphi 10.3.2 as per Embarcadero's instructions. So I'm asking this for upgrades I will be doing going forward.

Is there a way to export the MRU list from the Delphi IDE so it can be imported after an upgrade?

Comment: Try looking in the Registry, e.g. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\19.0\Closed Files` for Seattle.

Comment: @MartynA thank you for the reference to thos regestry values. Next time I'll save off those items so I have them. Unfortunately, BDS\19.0 is too old to have value for today. :-)

Comment: Yes, it would be (too old).  I find it really annoying that they using different (and unrelated) numbering in the registry compared with the public version number.  And even more annoying now the versions have names ...

Comment: But the names are only additions to the numbers. I like the names for day-to-day communication, because they are way more descriptive than the numbers - and less error prone. Rio Update 2 and Tokyo Update 3 are pretty clear, while 10.3.2 and 10.2.3 often need a second look.

Comment: For future reference, doing a complete uninstall is required, but one step of doing the uninstall asks if you want remove registry entries. If you answer that *No*, then your editor options and MRU list and those sorts of things stay, as do the paths for all your components and third-party tools. The migration tool isn't necessary for minor version updates (like 10.3.1 to 10.3.2). It may be necessary for major version updates (10.1 to 10.3, for instance).

Comment: @KenWhite 1. I do not recall being asked "do you want to remove registry entries". 2. Inside the D10.3.1 Migration Settings export file are the lat 15 closed files and last 10 closed projects. It would have been nice if the D10.3.2 Import Migration settings from file put them back.

Answer (score 0):

The list of Closed Files and Closed Projects is included in the Migrations Settings export file.

Simply open this file with an XML friendly text editor and look for these two sections:

```
<SettingGroup Name="Closed Files" Selected="true">
<SettingGroup Name="Closed Projects" Selected="true">
```

The reason I suggest an "XML" friendly text editor such as Notepad++ is this; I tried opening the migration settings file within the Delphi IDE and got and error message.

*Error - "One or more lines were too long and have been truncated"*

[image]

Unfortunately you have to open the "Closed Projects" one at a time from within the IDE to rebuild this list. In reality it only takes a few minutes to do and it get's the IDE's MRU list updated.